# Managing multiple spiders with scrapy

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am creating an aggregator and I started with scrapy as my initial tool set.
First I only had a few spiders, but as the project grows it seems like I may have hundreds or even a thousand different spiders as i scrape more and more sites.
What is the best way to manage these spiders as some websites only need to be crawled once, some on a more regular basis?
Is scrapy still a good tool when dealing with so many sites or would you recommend some other technology.

Comment: Take a look at [Scrapyd](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the project [scrapely](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely), that is from the creators of scrapy. But, as far as I know, it is not suitable for parsing sites containing javascript (more precisely, if the parsed data is not generated by javascript).